# Javascript regex matching string ending with number inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, numbers

I have the following regex patterns that matches all the **'act'** that ends with numbers within a list of URLs.

Regex pattern `/\/ch(\d+)\/act(\d+)/gi`

Javascript code

```
pageSrc[1] = "../ch01/index.html";
pageSrc[2] = "../ch01/act01/1.html";
pageSrc[3] = "../ch01/act01/2.html";
pageSrc[4] = "../ch01/act02/1.html";
pageSrc[5] = "../ch01/act02/2.html";
pageSrc[6] = "../ch01/actx/1.html";

var pattern = /\/ch(\d+)\/act(\d+)/gi;
for(var i=0; i<pageSrc.length; ++i){
  var hasAct = pattern.test(pageSrc[i]);
  console.log(hasAct);
}
```

The expected results and actual results

```
|   String   | Expected Result |   Actual Result  |
| pageSrc[1] |       false     |     false        |
| pageSrc[2] |       true      |     true         |
| pageSrc[3] |       true      |     *FALSE       |
| pageSrc[4] |       true      |     true         |
| pageSrc[5] |       true      |     *FALSE       |
| pageSrc[6] |       false     |     false        |
```

Am not sure why `pageSrc[3]` won't return `true`. I used the regEx tester on gskinner.com and it worked fine, here is the link http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?344ap

Can anyone help me take a look please? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `g` flag. From [the `RegExp.test` documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> As with `exec` (or in combination with it), `test` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

You don't want a global search when reusing a pattern like this.

```
> var pageSrc = [];
> pageSrc[1] = "../ch01/index.html";
  pageSrc[2] = "../ch01/act01/1.html";
  pageSrc[3] = "../ch01/act01/2.html";
  pageSrc[4] = "../ch01/act02/1.html";
  pageSrc[5] = "../ch01/act02/2.html";
  pageSrc[6] = "../ch01/actx/1.html";

  var pattern = /\/ch(\d+)\/act(\d+)/i;
  for(var i=0; i<pageSrc.length; ++i){
    var hasAct = pattern.test(pageSrc[i]);
    console.log(i, hasAct);
  }
  0 false
  1 false
  2 true
  3 true
  4 true
  5 true
  6 false
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `/g`. Remove that flag to make it work.

The `g` flag makes the regex start matching from `pattern.lastIndex` (the index where the previous match ended), until it fails, and then start at 0.

Comment: Thanks for replying, your solution works just as Matt's. Since i cannot mark 2 answers, i've up voted yours :) thanks again!